# Intent.getIntExtra() is giving unexpected results

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm publishing a notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder` class and adding an action button to it called *Cancel*
I expect, notification should get dismissed by clicking this action button. For this, I send a broadcast and attach notification id to `Intent` object by calling `putExtra(String, int)` on the `Intent`
The `BroadcastReceiver` receives the id of Notification by calling `getIntExtra(String, int)` and cancels the notification by calling `NotificationManagerCompat.cancel(id)`
But, everytime I try, the value of `id` that `BroadcastReceiver` receives is 8. Thus, I'm not able to cancel notifications.

Here is my code that adds the action buttons to the notification,

```
 Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActionReceiver.class);
 cancelIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
 cancelIntent.setAction(ACTION_DISMISS);
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
 Log.d(TAG, "Sent id: "+id);
 PendingIntent pendingCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, cancelIntent, 0);
 builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_dismiss, "Cancel", pendingCancelIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver class

```
 public class NotificationActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final static String TAG = NotificationActionReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive(), getAction == "+intent.getAction());

        switch (intent.getAction()){

            case MyActivity.ACTION_DISMISS:

                int id = intent.getIntExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, -1);
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "Notification id received: "+id);

                NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                managerCompat.cancel(id);
                break;

            case ....:
            ....
        }
    }
 }
```

The log cat always reports that The `BroadcastReciver` gets the value for notification id as 8

Comment: As @Nik says, you must use the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when generating the `PendingIntent`. This ensures that your "extras" will be in the `PendingIntent`. Otherwise, you will just end up with reference to an existing `PendingIntent` which may have other "extras" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing same thing and I am getting proper output:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Log.v(TAG," Notification id:" + model.getNotificationIdForLocalDB());

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent1.putExtra("notification_id", model.getNotificationIdForLocalDB());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, model.getNotificationIdForLocalDB(), intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And at BroadcastReceiver end :

```
if(intent != null){
            if(intent.getExtras() != null){
                notificationId = intent.getExtras().getInt("notification_id",0);
            }
        }
```

try to change Pending intent flag `0` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: What does the flags do??

Comment: see this link for flag information https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either of the following flags when building your `PendingIntent` (`PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call's 4th argument):

- [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), which keeps the `PendingIntent` if exists, but replaces its extra data with what is in the new Intent
- [FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT), which cancels existing `PendingIntent` if any, before creating new one.

Default behavior is that the extra data is not replaced (!!) if `PendingIntent` already exists.